# sidebar visible si te loggueas

Tags: reactjs, sidebar

**Buenas compañeros, soy bastante principiante en el mundo de la programación y más con el framework de React. Tengo el siguiente problema en mi código, necesito que cuando accedo bien logueado se muestre mi sidebar, pero cuando lo hago ahora mismo la barra sigue sin aparecer. Este es el código que tengo en el componente APP.
muchas gracias de antemano.**

```
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [showSideBar, setShowSideBar] = useState(false); // Nuevo estado para controlar la visibilidad del SideBar

  useEffect(() => {
    // Restablecer show a false cuando se monta el componente
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setShow(false);
    }, 4000);

    // Limpiar el timeout cuando el componente se desmonta o el estado showMessage cambia
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [show]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        {showSideBar && <SideBar />}
        {/* <SideBar /> */}
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <LoginForm
                onLogin={(token: string): void => {
                  if (token.length === 0) {
                    console.log("contraseña incorrecta");
                    _msgDlCabecera = "Error Login";
                    _msgDlgCuerpo = "Por favor, revise los datos introducidos.";
                    setShow(true);
                    setShowSideBar(false); // Ocultar el SideBar cuando el inicio de sesión falla
                  } else {
                    console.log(token);
                    setShowSideBar(true); //me muestra el sidebar si hay token correcto
                  }
                }}
              />
            }
          />
          <Route path="/backend" element={<BckHomePage />} />
          <Route path="/catalogo" element={<CatalogoPage />} />
          <Route path="/stocks" element={<StocksPage />} />
          <Route path="/tarifas" element={<TarifasPage />} />
          <Route path="/productos" element={<AgregarProductoPage />} />
          <Route path="/frontend" element={<FrontHomePage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      {show && (
        <ModalForm
          msgDlgCabecera={_msgDlCabecera}
          msgDlgCuerpo={_msgDlgCuerpo}
          boolShow={true}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

muchas gracias de antemano.